Enclosing an outdoor deck
I have a free-standing outdoor deck. It is 2 ft above the ground and the current decking is 1/2" x 6" with 1/2" spacing. It is in good shape. The deck is 12 ft x 16 ft. I want to enclose it as a 'garden room'. I want to use 1/2" 4 ft x 8 ft plywood as the floor. What underlayment should I use under the plywood and since the room will be enclosed do I need treated plywood. I would like to use the smooth surface ACX Araucoply sanded plywood. I plan on putting outdoor carpet over the plywood.  I live in the South. Any precautions or consideration to these plans?

Unless your garden room is going to cover your whole deck, do not just put the walls on the current deck floor.  A previous owner did that at our house, and now we're stuck with those deck boards underneath the walls, as it's not possible to remove them for replacement if the boards exposed to the outdoors need to be replaced.

1/2" x 6" does not sound like proper decking boards. Did you mean 1" x  6" ?  Also being in the south I would use treated plywood. Termites are an issue. The love to eat untreated wood.

Yes, decking boards are 1" x 6".

@RayHolt what is the joist span? The deck boards do not seem adequately structural, and so converting this space to a sun room could fail under typical loads.

My deck joists are 2 ft apart in both directions and every intersection has a cemented post. It is very adequately structural. Also, the 2 ft space above the ground allows for plenty of ventilation.
